# How to open popup when anchor in url

Tags: jquery, popup, anchor

How can i open a div which have an id of a specific link `<a>` and open it when user write the url with the hashtag, Example :

**The link :**

```
<a href="https://jobs.cegid-webfactory.dev.ci.alterway.fr/fr/test-group-popin/#popin-1">POPIN 1</a>
```

**the popin :**

```
<div id="popin-1" class="wp-block-group is-style-popin popOpen" style="display: none;">
    <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
        <h3>POPIN 1</h3>
        <p class="has-white-color has-accent-background-color has-text-color has-background">Textze dans le groupe de la popin</p>
        <p class="has-white-color has-accent-background-color has-text-color has-background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="close-popin icon-close"></div>
</div>
```

Js :

```
var fn_popin = function () {
  $("a").each(function (i, el) {
    $(".is-style-popin").hide();
    $(el).click(function (event) {

      $(".is-style-popin").each(function (j, pop) {
        my_popin = $(this);
        my_popinID = my_popin.attr("id");

        url = $(el).attr("href").split("#")[1];

        if (my_popinID === url) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          my_popin.append("<div class='close-popin icon-close'></div>");
          my_popin.show();
          my_popin.addClass("popOpen");

          $("body").addClass("open-popin");

          $(pop)
          .find($(".close-popin"))
          .click(function () {
            $(pop).hide();
            $("body").removeClass("open-popin");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

If i copy the URL (https://jobs.cegid-webfactory.dev.ci.alterway.fr/fr/test-group-popin/#popin-1) ans past it in browser the popin must appear

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?  You have code to get the id from the url.  It looks like you can do `$("#" + id)` and then you already have the code to add/show it.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Example, if i copy the URL and past it in browser, i need to show the popin

Comment: No *"what problem are you trying to solve"* - you've already described that adequately.  I'm asking why you think you can't do it, given that you have everything you need in the code provided - which part of the code are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @freedomn-m it's when the i past the URL and press enter. This action should display the popin, i know i already have the code to open the popin, but just when i click the button